# Processing URL Queries (Django & JSON)

Tags: python, json, django, url

I want to have a webpage return JSON based off of the URL Query. How can I do this?

I have a server with Django (and obviously python) installed.

Any sort of answer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

-CJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You migh want to use `json.dumps()` to help you convert dictionary to json as well as use `HttpResponse` in `django.http`.
A rough example could be:

views.py:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get_mydata(request):
    response = dict()
    response['status'] = 'success'
    response['msg'] = 'hello, CJ'
    .... # more key-value pair as you need
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type="application/json")
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^get_data/', views.get_mydata, name='get_mydata')
)
```

html/javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "GET",
    "dataType": "json",
    "url": "/get_data/",
    "success": function(result) {
        console.log(result); // here you get the json response from get_mydata() in views.py
    }
})
```

Comment: Looks really good! I'm still a bit confused as to where this script would be located. If you could explain, or point me to a good tutorial, that'd be awesome!!

Comment: @CJGoldshine This is close to what I mean: http://bixly.com/blog/json-jquery-and-django/

Comment: That answers part of my question, but in what file would this script be located in?

Comment: @CJGoldshine it's a little perplexing that you're having trouble here. For anything at all in Django, if you want to return something from a URL, you use a view. The fact that you haven't understood that implies that you should really do the introductory tutorial.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the criticism! I've already done introductory tutorials, but I'm new to Django. Sorry.

Comment: @CJGoldshine See my updated example